# Laravel 8 mews captcha return invalid every time

Tags: return, captcha, laravel-8

I have installed mews captcha in laravel 8. Everything is fine. Captcha is loading every time. But when I input the captcha form it returns "The given data was invalid" in the console.
**Here is my controller**

```
public function FptEditReq(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'captcha' => 'required|captcha',
    ]);
    
    $revision = fpt::find($request->id);
    $revision->revision = '1';
    $revision->save();
    return response()->json('success');
}
```

**This is my view code**

```
 <form class="form-sample" id="captcha_form" method="post" action="javascript:void(0)">
  @csrf
  <div class="form-group mt-4 mb-4">

   <div class="captcha">
     <span>{!! captcha_img() !!}</span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" class="reload" id="reload">
          &#x21bb;
     </button>
     </div>
   </div>

    <div class="form-group mb-4 col-sm-2">
       <input id="captcha" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Captcha" name="captcha" required="">
     </div>                               
                                              
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mr-2" id="editreq">Edit Request</button>
                                        
  </form>
```

**This is in my javascript**

```
$('#reload').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'formation-plate-test/reload-captcha',
        success: function (data) {
            $(".captcha span").html(data.captcha);
        }

    });
});

$('body').on('click', '#editreq', function () {
var id = $('#captcha_form input[name="id"]').val();
 $.post("{{route('fpt.editreq')}}",{
      id:id,
 },
   function(data){
  if (data=='success') {

  location.reload(); 
        
      }
    })
 });
```

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you have to refresh your captcha div after ajax return.

```
$('#reload').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'formation-plate-test/reload-captcha',
        success: function (data) {
            $(".captcha span").html(data.captcha);
            $(".captcha").load(window.location.href + " .captcha");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this package for your laravel projects

```
composer require hpd/captcha
```

Validation:

```
Route::post('captcha_check', function() {
        $validator = validator()->make(request()->all(), 
            ['captcha' => 'required|captcha'];
        );
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            echo '<p style="color: #ff0000;">Incorrect!</p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p style="color: #00ff00;">Matched </p>';
        }

});
```

View:

```
    <div>
      {{!! captcha_get_html()!!}}
    </div>
```